# Problems while connectring app to MongoDB on Azure

Tags: mongodb, azure

I tried connectiong to Mongo on Azure and while working on local host everything went fine, here I got this problem

Exception in thread "cluster-ClusterId{value='63d3d50e34b36c0f2a6720cb', description='my corp'}-mongo.cosmos.azure.com:PORT" com.mongodb.MongoInterruptedException: Interrupted waiting for lock
java.base/java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantLock$Sync.lockInterruptibly(ReentrantLock.java:159)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantLock.lockInterruptibly(ReentrantLock.java:372)
at com.mongodb.internal.Locks.checkedWithLock(Locks.java:41)

I tried updating pom to latest versions of dependencies etc. but nothing seems to work

Answer (score 0):

As per error stated "mongodb.MongoInterruptedException: Interrupted waiting for lock".   Issue may caused due to
some other thread called

```
 MongoClient.close()
```

same error appear when you open multiple mongodb instances. Make sure that are closing the mongo clients before open a new instance.

```
MongoClient mongo = new MongoClient ("localhost", 27017);
mongo.close();
```

I have found sample application [tutorial](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#data.nosql.mongodb)